# If a markov chain is in a recurrent communication class, will it stay or leave the class?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I see intuitively that if it is recurrent, the chain will return to the particular state it is in with probability 1. And because that state it is in is in a particular recurrence class, with recurrence being a classwide property, it will always stay in that class. How do I prove this formally?

Comment: This is a consequence of the definitions, what is there to prove, exactly?

Comment: A proof is provided in the book *Stochastic Processes* by *Parzen* p222-224.